# Connect Windows 7 Laptop to Mac mini

Tags: mac, windows, screen, sharing

I have a Mac mini and a Windows 7 laptop.  I want to control the Mac mini through my Windows laptop.  Is there any solution in a way that I don't have to hook up the Mac with a monitor, keyboard, and mouse every time I want to connect?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: To answer the question that was removed, "_Is there is way to connect between them with a ethernet cable and then use the Wi-Fi in my Windows laptop for Internet access?_", yes this can be done however you'll need to post it as a new question to get detailed answer(s) to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar scenario in that I need to access a Linux system on my LAN from my MacBook Pro, so I use the free version of [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com). It's available for Windows, Linux and OS X.

You first have to hook up a monitor, keyboard, and mouse to get NoMachine installed and configured on the Mac and then connect at least once from the Windows system.  You could then shutdown the Mac mini, unplug monitor, keyboard, and mouse and then restart the Mac mini.  I'm assuming you also have it set to auto login.

It would need to be installed on both the Windows and Mac systems.